# Extracting Key Value pairs from a String using Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, web-scraping

I have a web scrapped string containing key value pairs i.e `firstName:"Quaran", lastName:"McPherson"`

```
st = '{"accountId":405266,"firstName":"Quaran","lastName":"McPherson","accountIdentifier":"StudentAthlete","profilePicUrl":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1331475329014181888/4z19KrCf.jpg","networkProfileCode":"quaran-mcpherson","hasDeals":true,"activityMin":11,"sports":["Men\'s Basketball","Basketball"],"currentTeams":["Nebraska Cornhuskers"],"previousTeams":[],"facebookReach":null,"twitterReach":619,"instagramReach":0,"linkedInReach":null},{"accountId":375964,"firstName":"Micole","lastName":"Cayton","accountIdentifier":"StudentAthlete","profilePicUrl":"https://opendorsepr.blob.core.windows.net/media/375964/20220622223838_46dbe3fd-a683-436b-84d4-90c84a5af35f.jpg","networkProfileCode":"micole-cayton","hasDeals":true,"activityMin":16,"sports":["Basketball","Women\'s Basketball"],"currentTeams":["Minnesota Golden Gophers"],"previousTeams":["Cal Berkeley Golden Bears"],"facebookReach":0,"twitterReach":1273,"instagramReach":5700,"linkedInReach":null}'
```

I am trying to extract the first_name, last_name and a few other parameters from this string in list format such that I will be having a first_name list with all first_names from the string

I tried using `re.findall('"firstName":'"(.*)\S$",st)` to access the text `"Quaran"` but result is coming in the following format

`'"Quaran","lastName":"McPherson","accountIdentifier":"StudentAthlete","profilePicUrl":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1331475329014181888/4z19KrCf.jpg","networkProfileCode":"quaran-mcpherson","hasDeals":true,"activityMin":11,"sports":["Men\'s Basketball","Basketball"],"currentTeams":["Nebraska Cornhuskers"],"previousTeams":[],"facebookReach":null,"twitterReach":619,"instagramReach":0,"linkedInReach":null}`

how do I end the specify within the regex to end the search at the end of the name in quotes??

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex `(?<=\"firstName\":\").*?(?=\")`. The ? in the middle makes it a lazy match, so that it stops matching as soon as it finds a " character.

I want to add that that with backtracking, there can be an exponential performance penalty. I can do something like this `"firstName":"(.*?)"` and extract the capturing group so that there will only a linear performance penalty.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/uM2l8M/1

Python code

```py
import re
st = '{"accountId":405266,"firstName":"Quaran","lastName":"McPherson","accountIdentifier":"StudentAthlete","profilePicUrl":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1331475329014181888/4z19KrCf.jpg","networkProfileCode":"quaran-mcpherson","hasDeals":true,"activityMin":11,"sports":["Men\'s Basketball","Basketball"],"currentTeams":["Nebraska Cornhuskers"],"previousTeams":[],"facebookReach":null,"twitterReach":619,"instagramReach":0,"linkedInReach":null},{"accountId":375964,"firstName":"Micole","lastName":"Cayton","accountIdentifier":"StudentAthlete","profilePicUrl":"https://opendorsepr.blob.core.windows.net/media/375964/20220622223838_46dbe3fd-a683-436b-84d4-90c84a5af35f.jpg","networkProfileCode":"micole-cayton","hasDeals":true,"activityMin":16,"sports":["Basketball","Women\'s Basketball"],"currentTeams":["Minnesota Golden Gophers"],"previousTeams":["Cal Berkeley Golden Bears"],"facebookReach":0,"twitterReach":1273,"instagramReach":5700,"linkedInReach":null}'
pattern = re.compile('"firstName":"(.*?)"')

for match in pattern.finditer(st):
    print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. One question, what if the substring I am trying to match with is a number ? like instead of 'firstName' I want to extract the 'instagramReach' which is stored as a number? I am unable to capture it right now with the .*?(?= bit, do you have a suggestion here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The end character is not a quotation mark, so you would change it to a comma. `(?<=\"instagramReach\":).*?(?=,)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<="firstName":")[^"\r\n]+
```

`(?<="firstName":")` go to the point where `"firstName":"` appeasrs in the string,

`[^"\r\n]+` then match one or more character except `"`, `\r` and `\n`. not to cross the second double quote of the firstName value and  not to cross any newline.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AHm0lC/1).

See [python demo](https://tio.run/##pZJbj9owEIXf@RWRXwA1kCshoKKqUKlarVjRm/qw3a6cZEJcHDsdO4to1d9OHW6C3e2@NC@Rj8@xZuabaqMLKYLtlpWVRG0htFpKW5P2b0LTVNZCX2VkHLoDP4pskjNU@oaWQMbkQ02RCmITTk/aPF0UgEo28ikOQrOcAZr7T7pujm91wUGDMVUoc8ZhwdIvyI2h0LpSY8epEtXXa1Yu@6ksnYPrnpV0CcrxgsALh4PAH7le6MVeHMdO@MsbXeMs7/@oluZdAXotcbXYB2cya6r7uau4V6bVqciCqndAuSJjjTU0RWv2wPRmzgQZe55NVDMVc31L5iC@tZU1pWoFOqGcm/jZ4c4maY1ouvsMtNwlbiBBY6DWTKIoamNF1fgqhAcma3U0GimnKSRSrj4CTQsyFjXnNjED0BrwoEXeyCZMKE2XSMuD6JrxM7GC7EqcRf/YF/SC4WAUhZf05iyVHC7pzehG/z86WYHIJCqosJ9wmRiCCP01M@Ja9Q0Yp4SMUWdfleO7vu9GvvmCOIjvwyhLIMizHo3ioBcGUdKLwyzsjdw0DumA5sHgRcblrq9eemzlZcDROeALsl9l@YT3M4jNMwKU1NR6L7mZj/ntlus5zGa@3JoCroDD5uifAt27H22A@xi/5w@Dp/wHQ/cfK9ButSra5IU1sbDdefN6crEA3dvv5O5V40ImdMcgyg0i02bnELMtpbvd7fYv).

Answer (score 1):

Your string seems JSON array, you can easily parse json in any language if it's valid. To make your string valid add '[' at first and ']' at last of your string then parse the JSON in your language. Such as

##### JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(st)
```

##### Python:

```
import json
dict = json.loads(st)
```

##### Regular expression:

if you strictly wish to parse using regular expression use:

```
/(?:\"|\')(?<key>[\w\d]+)(?:\"|\')(?:\:\s*)(?:\"|\')?(?<value>[\w\s-]*)(?:\"|\')?/gm
```